# In Autofac how do I change the instance that is registered after Build has been called?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

So lets say i have this code

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterInstance(new MyType());
var container = builder.Build();
```

Then some time later I want to change the instance of `MyType` for all future resolves that are called on `container`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

At the time you want to change the registration, create a new `ContainerBuilder`, register the new instance, and call `Update` passing in the container:

```
// at some later point...
builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterInstance(myType2);
builder.Update(container);
```

Comment: Update(container) has been obsoleted. It is recommended to rebuild the container.

Comment: When there are 500 unit test cases to run, I think rebuilding containers for each of the case will be very inefficiency. Overriding services across cases is a considerable workaround in this case.

Comment: FYI, See this discussion https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/811#issuecomment-272428072

Answer (score 21):

An alternative could be to register a delegate that is able to change the underlying instance provided by the container. Consider the following code:

```
 var theInstance = new MyType();
 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
 builder.Register(context => theInstance);
 builder.Register<Action<MyType>>(context => newInstance => theInstance = newInstance);
 var container = builder.Build();
```

You can now resolve the action to get a delegate that can change the registration:

```
 var updateInstance = c.Resolve<Action<MyType>>();
 updateInstance(new MyType());
```

**Note:** if you could elaborate on *when* and *why* you need to change the instance, perhaps we could even find a better solution.

Comment: When there are 500 unit test cases to run, I think rebuilding containers for each of the case will be inefficiency. Overriding services across cases is a considerable workaround in this case.

Comment: @JijieChen those 500 unit tests, do they really need a full-built container in order to run? If so, I would feel that I did too much in those tests, hence they are more akin to integration tests than unit tests.

Comment: Well I partially agree with you that these cases can be more like integrate tests. Consider a class `C` has 5 dependents and in a unit test scenario, you'll need to declare these objects and seed them into the  `C` manually. During a refactoring, there is much possibility that you'll need to change all the test cases...which is costly. It's a balance by reusing dependent instances resolved from DI and overriding ones you want to customize to satisfy your test case.

Comment: @JijieChen I agree, that will probably be a maintenance issue. Though one could argue that too many dependencies is actually a code smell and could indicate that your classes is doing too much. But that is a discussion for another thread I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of the Autofac Lifetime event "OnActivating" and have your own controller object in memory which replaces the resolved instance like so

```
builder.Register<TInterface>(c => c.Resolve<TConcrete>())
       .OnActivating(e => e.ReplaceInstance(new TInterfaceSubclass()));
```

https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/events.html#onactivating